# Everytime I start SQL Server Agent job I get an error log

Tags: sql-server-agent, sql-server-2016

Every time I start an Sql Server job, I get the following error.
I am using SQL Server 2016. Does not anybody know how to fix it?

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {2DC39BD2-9CFF-405D-A2FE-D246C976278C}
>    and APPID 
>   {DB336D8E-32E5-42B9-B14B-58AAA87CEB06}
>    to the user NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT SID (S-1-5-80-344959196-2060754871-2302487193-2804545603-1466107430) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft have published an article on just this issue.  2014 and 2012 instructions are on the same page.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213130.aspx.

> In previous versions of SQL Server, by default when you installed SQL Server all users in the Users group had access to the Integration Services service. When you install the current release of SQL Server, users do not have access to the Integration Services service.  The service is secure by default. After SQL Server is installed, the administrator must grant access to the service.
>
> To grant access to the Integration Services service:
>
> 1. Run Dcomcnfg.exe.  Dcomcnfg.exe provides a user interface for modifying certain settings in the registry.
> 2. In the Component Services dialog, expand the Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config node.
> 3. Right-click Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 13.0, and then click Properties.
> 4. On the Security tab, click Edit in the Launch and Activation Permissions area.
> 5. Add users and assign appropriate permissions, and then click OK.
> 6. Repeat steps 4 to 5 for Access Permissions.
> 7. Restart SQL Server Management Studio.
> 8. Restart the Integration Services Service.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not an expert on component services security, but I am someone who has seen similar errors a few times and fixed them according to advice I found on the web. This assumes you are a member of the machine's Administrators group. The idea is to make Administrators the owner of the class and the app, which empowers you in Component Services to grant the needed launch and activate permissions on the components.

- Run RegEdit as administrator
- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID
- Find the CLSID noted in your error message, click on it and see what class it is. Right click for properties and see who owns it. (In my case it was a Windows 10 freeze issue, and the CLSID was for Runtime Broker, and it was owned by TrustedInstaller. Following advice I found on the web I clicked Advanced, and changed the owner to Administrators. Then I gave Administrators "Full Control" while ensuring TrustedInstaller also still had full control.
- Next, go to HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\AppID and click the AppID from your error message. Note it's name. Make the ownership/permissions changes there as well.
- Next run Component Cervices as administrator and drill down to Console Root\Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config.
- For each of the components whose names you found in the Registry

  - right click and choose Properties
  - Click the "Security" tab
  - Under "Launch and Activation Permissions", click "customize", and "Edit"
  - Add "LOCAL SERVICE" as a user
  - Grant "local launch" and "local activation" permissions to LOCAL SERVICE

Good Luck!